# VB.Net No value given for one or more required parameters with update

Tags: database, vb.net

Hi I am trying to a build a booking system for my work that communicates with a currently existing database. But I am having trouble getting it to commit the changes to the database.

I am getting this error.

> "No value given for one or more required parameters with update"

Below is my code for injecting the changes to the access database. I have replaced some sensitive information with asterix's. Thankyou.

```
Private Sub AddAddButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddAddButton.Click

    Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\*******************************;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=**********;")
    Try
        Dim cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("UPDATE RepairOrders SET ROOther = @Other, ROJobType = @Type, ROJobTime = @Time, RODelPicDate = @DelPic WHERE RONo = @JobNo", conn)

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Other", AddOtherText.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", AddTypeCombo.Text)
        If AddTimeCombo.Text = "AM" Then
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", "1")
        ElseIf AddTimeCombo.Text = "PM" Then
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", "2")
        Else
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", "0")
        End If
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DelPic", AddDatePick.Value.Date)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@JobNo", AddJobText.Text)

        conn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("Booking Added!", "test")
        conn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: What if `AddTimeCombo` is blank or has some other input?

Comment: I haven't implemented a situation to deal with blank fields yet. but all the fields were filled in. I just want to get it to work before messing around with all the failsafes.

I ammended my code in the OP for it to deal if something else is put in the AddTimeCombo. Thanks for that.

Comment: what are the `not null` fields in table `RepairOrders` ? it will be easy to get the correct answer if you show your `RepairOrders` _table's_ structure also

Comment: are you sure that all your controls `*.text` have values ?!

Comment: Everything has a value. http://i58.tinypic.com/2r219nm.png

Comment: Good question, I cannot see an obvious error. For debugging, I would suggest that you reduce your SQL statement parameter by parameter until the error disappears -- that should tell you where the culprit is. As a side note: You should use [`Using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) with OleDbConnection and OleDbCommand to prevent memory leaks.

Comment: Ok after cancelling all others out, it turns out that the AddOtherText textbox is the one that is causing the conflict.